# Bash script how to run a command remotely and then exit the remote terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, remote-access

I'm trying to execute the command:

`ssh nvidia@ubuntu-ip-address "/opt/ads2/arm-linux64/bin/ads2 svcd &"`

This works so far except that it hangs in the remote terminal when `"/opt/ads2/arm-linux64/bin/ads2 svcd&"` is executed, unless i enter ctrl+c (see image below).

[image]

So I'm looking for a command that, after executing the `"/opt/ads2/arm-linux64/bin/ads2 svcd &"` command, exits from the remote terminal and continue executing the local bash script.

Below is the bash script i'm working on

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Welcome to ADS2 Session Start..."

while  true 
do
echo "Starting service Daemon on the targert"
echo "Enter the ip-address of the target"
read x
if [ -z "$x" ]
then 
    echo "ip-address is empty"
else
    echo "Connecting with target..."
    if [[ $x =~ ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$ || $x =~ ^fdt-c-agx-[0-9][0- 
      9][0-9][0-9]$ ]]
    then
        ssh nvidia@"$x"   "/opt/ads2/arm-linux64/bin/ads2 svcd &"; exit 0 
        if ! ssh nvidia@"$x"
        then
            echo -e "\033[31mconnection failed\e[0m" 
        else
            echo -e "\033[32m connection succeded\e[0m"
        
            break
        fi
    else
        "Make sure the io address in the coorect form"  
    fi

fi
done
```

Comment: Try `/opt/ads2/arm-linux64/bin/ads2 svcd &; exit 0`.

Comment: @Jos. I tried your suggestion, it executes on the remote --> `nvidia   12040  0.2  0.0  39700 23872 ?        Ssl  12:48   0:00 /opt/ads2/arm-linux64/bin/ads2svcd`. However, still hangs on the local and exits everything when i press ctrl+c. which i don't want, because there is a rest-code that must be executed

Comment: @Jos. I've added the complete code